# PyQt - QPushButton loop

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm new to Python and PyQt so sorry if I can't describe my problems clearly. I want to do a cinema seat selector UI and this is the code I have made below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication)

class Ui2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui2, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('seat.ui', self)
        self.A1.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
        self.B1.clicked.connect(self.greenButton)
        self.show()

    def greenButton(self):
        self.B1.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
        self.B1.clicked.connect(self.whiteButton)

    def whiteButton(self):
        self.B1.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.B1.clicked.connect(self.greenButton)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui2()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is, if I click the button B1 multiple times the program will freeze - I read it somewhere that this is caused by full memory.

Also this is only for the button B1, what should I do if I want to implement the same functions for all buttons?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call self.B1.clicked.connect so many times.  Each time you call that function, it registers another event handler.  When the button is clicked, all the event handlers that have ever been registered get called.  So as you keep clicking, each click causes more and more things to happen.  Eventually it fails.

In general you want to try to have *one* handler for each event.  Here is one simple way to do that:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication)

class Ui2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui2, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('seat.ui', self)
        self.b1_color = "green"
        self.A1.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
        self.B1.clicked.connect(self.onButton)
        self.show()

    def onButton(self):
        if self.b1_color == "green":
            self.b1_color = "white"
        else:
            self.b1_color = "green"
        self.B1.setStyleSheet("background-color: " + self.b1_color)
```

Tested with PySide and Qt4.8, but it should still work in your environment (I hope).

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm. Also, can you tell me what I should do to use this function on all buttons (e.g. A1, A2, B1, B2 ...) without creating functions for each of the buttons?

Comment: I always prefer to have one event handler function for each event, even if there are events of the same type on different widgets.  If there is common functionality among several handlers, I factor that out into a separate method.  Then I call that method from each handler.  Sometimes this results in a lot of little functions, but the performance penalty is usually insignificant and the code is easier to read and understand.